# Combining AND and OR in MongoDB queries

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I'm building a pretty complex search formula for an automotive website that is using mongo for their auto storage. Most of it I have found to be very straightforward. It currently supports filtering by body style, new/used, etc. Where I'm running into a problem, though, is where it defaults to both new and used vehicles, since they will both have a separate price range (calculated low and high prices based on a monthly payment range). How can I make this work?

For example, if it's just a used auto, we're using this (CodeIgniter) code:

```
$this->mongo_db->where('stock_type', 'used');
$this->mongo_db->where_between('internet_price', $amounts['bottom_amt_used'], $amounts['top_amt_used']);
```

We do something similar for new cars. Works great on their own. How do I combine these so that I can find

- IF stock_type = new, WHERE_BETWEEN(a, b)
- OR IF stock_type = false, WHERE_BETWEEN(c, d)

And combine this with other filters, like WHERE body_style IN (...)?

We are using CodeIgniter and Alex Bilbie's mongodb library, which might complicate things here, I'm thinking.

Answer (score 0):

In the Mongo shell the query is pretty straight forward.  You can use something like:

```
db.vehicle_stock.find({ $or: [ { stock_type: 'used', internet_price: { $gte: 123, $lte: 145 }}, { stock_type: 'new', internet_price: { $gte: 161, $lte: 184 }} ]});
```

You could try something similar with Alex Bilbie's library:

```
$this.mongo_db->where(array(
  '$or' => array(
    array( 'stock_type' => 'used', 'internet_price' => array( '$gte' => 123, '$lte' => 145 )),
    array( 'stock_type' => 'new', 'internet_price' => array( '$gte' => 161, '$lte' => 184 ))
  )
));
```